# 6001 Redirected outside allowed domains

Tags: .htaccess, http, web-hosting, redirection

I have noticed that visits on my clients site have lowered much in last 2 weeks, so i checked all scripts Java, php, .htaccess all posibilities, pinged from worldwide, using 100 tools for pings availbility so on but all seams fine, except on this site http://www.watchmouse.com where it says:

```
Redirected outside allowed domains 6001 - München, D2
Redirected outside allowed domains 6001 - München, D2
Redirected outside allowed domains 6001 - New York, NY
Redirected outside allowed domains 6001 - Toronto, C2
Redirected outside allowed domains 6001 - Amsterdam1, N1
Redirected outside allowed domains 6001 - Manchester, U2
Redirected outside allowed domains 6001 - Lisbon, PT
Redirected outside allowed domains 6001 - Florida, FL
so on...
```

can anyone help around this? is this some hosting provider fault or? how to be sure?
if i ping i get right IP address but that means nothing if some script is redirecting after page load or some gateway!

Comment: sry didnt mention, i open site normaly, site is working. but its not normal to lose 80% traffic wich was 10000 daily visits and costant new content

Comment: I'd recommend you ask them what this error message means.

Comment: they don't know: That's really strange. Redirected outside allowed domains, probably your domain is not allowed in those locations. Sorry, but at the moment we don't know how this can happen.

Comment: found out what the problem was? Got the exact same error at watchmouse.

Answer (score 1):

First, 6001 is not the 'real' or official HTTP error code. At least not to the best of my knowledge and not in [HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

It seems to me that is some custom error code, invented by watchmouse.com for their own purposes of naming the errors they see in some more details.

I suppose you get it (as I do) under the category of 'real browser check' performed by WatchMouse?
That seems to be their effort to measure 'real' response of your page when visited from 'real' browser, as the real user would do. 
I see that check is done each 30 min - question is do they actually make a visit by real browser each half an hour or they have some automatic job to do a HTTP request to your domain, while presenting itself through browser's signature as IE, Chrome, Firefox etc.

I suspect it's the latter and that they either don't manage to 'cloak' themselves properly so that your domain/page recognizes them in some way as a non-browser (or a spider) which causes breaks of your page(s) functionality.

Do you have any conditioning on your site, related to browser's 'user agent' string that would alter the behavior of your page?

I saw such errors in 100% test-visits for some domains, while actually I was able to see that domain working fully and properly in all browsers in 100% of cases, so I'm a bit suspicious to that 'browser check' thing.
But I'll be investigating further and will let you know if I manage to solve it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Email from WatchMouse support:

> Regarding your question about the 6001 code error, it is a redirect
>   error. For browser monitors this can probably be fixed at the monitor
>   settings, by changing the configuration "Allow browser to make
>   requests to" to "The internet".